# Nuance Recognizer Error Issue

Tags: android

I'm working with the Nuance Android SDK. I'm trying to initialize a new recognizer immediately after canceling another recognizer. However, right now it seems like the new recognizer goes to error after that.

So what I want to happen is to cancel a recognizer and initialize a new recognizer in one button click. It works perfectly fine if I do it in two button clicks but it always goes to error when I was trying to make it happen in one button click. Below is the code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (_currentRecognizer != null) 
        { 
            _currentRecognizer.stopRecording(); 
        } 
        _currentRecognizer = MainActivity.getSpeechKit().createRecognizer(Recognizer.RecognizerType.Dictation, Recognizer.EndOfSpeechDetection.Long, Constants.Speech2TextTable.get(source), _listener, _handler); 
        _currentRecognizer.start(); 
        isRecording = true; 
}
```

And in the console, it returns the following:

```
07-27 17:13:02.464 5415-5458/com.sws.translate I/SpeechKit﹕ Starting recognize transaction 
07-27 17:13:02.464 5415-5460/com.sws.translate D/NMSP_﹕ [co] loadResource 
07-27 17:13:02.464 5415-5460/com.sws.translate E/NMSP﹕ [b] ANDROID_CONTEXT parameter is not passed in!!! 
07-27 17:13:02.484 5415-5460/com.sws.translate E/NMSP﹕ [b] ANDROID_CONTEXT parameter is not passed in!!! 
07-27 17:13:02.484 5415-5460/com.sws.translate I/NMSP﹕ [dk] appendLogToQueryBegin: NMSPDefines.DEVICE_CMD_LOG_TO_SERVER_ENABLED is disabled 
07-27 17:13:02.484 5415-5458/com.sws.translate I/SpeechKit﹕ Starting recorder 
07-27 17:13:02.484 5415-5460/com.sws.translate D/NMSP_﹕ [dk] PDXCommandCreated() called from handleInit()c7c85b31-e625-49ab-a239-2f9d6c28876a:12 (com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.dk@42ca4d48,com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.r$1@42ca3bc0) 
07-27 17:13:02.684 5415-5458/com.sws.translate I/SpeechKit﹕ Capturing audio from recorder 
07-27 17:13:04.454 5415-5458/com.sws.translate I/SpeechKit﹕ Stopping recorder 
07-27 17:13:04.624 5415-5460/com.sws.translate I/SpeechKit﹕ Recorder stopped 
07-27 17:13:04.624 5415-5458/com.sws.translate I/SpeechKit﹕ Transaction error code: 5 
07-27 17:13:04.624 5415-5458/com.sws.translate D/NMSP_﹕ [cp] freeResource() disconnectTimeout:0 
07-27 17:13:04.624 5415-5458/com.sws.translate I/SpeechKit﹕ Starting recognize transaction 
07-27 17:13:04.624 5415-5460/com.sws.translate D/NMSP_﹕ [co] loadResource 
07-27 17:13:04.634 5415-5460/com.sws.translate E/NMSP﹕ [b] ANDROID_CONTEXT parameter is not passed in!!! 
07-27 17:13:04.634 5415-5460/com.sws.translate D/NMSP_﹕ [co] loadResource 
07-27 17:13:04.634 5415-5460/com.sws.translate E/NMSP﹕ [b] ANDROID_CONTEXT parameter is not passed in!!! 
07-27 17:13:04.634 5415-5460/com.sws.translate E/NMSP﹕ [b] ANDROID_CONTEXT parameter is not passed in!!! 
07-27 17:13:04.634 5415-5460/com.sws.translate I/NMSP﹕ [dk] appendLogToQueryBegin: NMSPDefines.DEVICE_CMD_LOG_TO_SERVER_ENABLED is disabled 
07-27 17:13:04.634 5415-5458/com.sws.translate I/SpeechKit﹕ Starting recorder 
07-27 17:13:04.634 5415-5460/com.sws.translate D/NMSP_﹕ [dk] PDXCommandCreated() called from handleInit()c7c85b31-e625-49ab-a239-2f9d6c28876a:14 (com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.dk@4250f4e8,com.nuance.nmdp.speechkit.r$1@424f0be8) 
07-27 17:13:04.844 5415-5458/com.sws.translate I/SpeechKit﹕ Capturing audio from recorder 
07-27 17:13:10.854 5415-5460/com.sws.translate I/SpeechKit﹕ Recorder event (end of speech) 
07-27 17:13:10.854 5415-5460/com.sws.translate I/SpeechKit﹕ Recorder stopped 
07-27 17:13:15.694 5415-5460/com.sws.translate D/NMSP_﹕ [dk] PDXTransactionImpl.onQueryRetry() 
07-27 17:13:15.694 5415-5460/com.sws.translate D/NMSP_﹕ [dh] PDXQueryRetry.getCause() 
07-27 17:13:15.694 5415-5460/com.sws.translate D/NMSP_﹕ [dh] PDXQueryRetry.getName() 
07-27 17:13:15.694 5415-5460/com.sws.translate I/SpeechKit﹕ PDX Query Retry Returned: 1(AUDIO_INFO) 
07-27 17:13:15.694 5415-5460/com.sws.translate D/NMSP_﹕ [dh] PDXQueryRetry.getPrompt() 
07-27 17:13:15.704 5415-5460/com.sws.translate D/NMSP_﹕ [dh] PDXQueryRetry.getName() 
07-27 17:13:15.704 5415-5458/com.sws.translate I/SpeechKit﹕ Transaction error code: 2 
07-27 17:13:15.704 5415-5458/com.sws.translate I/SpeechKit﹕ Transaction suggestion: Sorry, speech not recognized. Please try again. 
07-27 17:13:15.714 5415-5458/com.sws.translate D/NMSP_﹕ [cp] freeResource() disconnectTimeout:0 
07-27 17:13:15.744 5415-5415/com.sws.translate D/Nuance SampleVoiceApp﹕ Recognizer.Listener.onError: session id [c7c85b31-e625-49ab-a239-2f9d6c28876a]
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I was working on Speechkit SDK long time ago. I believe the problem here is that your second transaction starts after the hardware recognizer actually stops. When you receive "Recorder event (end of speech)", this event stops the current recorder, therefore you record no audio.

You can try waiting for end-of-speech event before terminating the recorder, or if it is allowed you can use the same recorder object for the second recognition. Adding an initial "recording start sound" sometimes fixes this type of issues. If it doesn't solve it, try using Nuance forum or support pages at developer.nuance.com